# How to deal with Null for custom condition in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm finding the best way to find a variable is null on the custom condition.

I tried to compare null. However, Azure Pipeline complains cause error, if I configure like this.

```
and(failed(), ne(variables['Some'], Null))
```

Also, This configuration doesn't throw an error, however, when the 'Some' is null, the condition becomes false. Since Null and 'Null' is different.

```
and(failed(), ne(variables['Some'], 'Null'))
```

I eventually come up with a workaround. However, it is not cool way. I add PowerShell task, and create this script.

```bsh
if ($env:Some -eq $null) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipSome]True"
}
```

then configure custom condition

```
and(failed(), ne(variables['SkipSome'], 'True'))
```

I expect there is a way to compare with null without the powershell. However, I can't find it on the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you Leo, Your answer works! My case was the variables are not defined, however, it works, perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

> How to deal with Null for custom condition in Azure Pipeline?

**To deal with Null for custom condition, we should use `''` instead of `Null` or `'Null'`**.

You can check the [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#string-1) for some details.

So, you can configure it like following:

```
and(failed(), ne(variables['Some'], ''))
```

To test it more intuitively, I change the `ne` to `eq`:

```
and(failed(), eq(variables['Some'], ''))
```

Then I set the variable is empty on the Variable tab, and add a Inline powershell task with above condition:

[image]

[image]

In the log, we could see that task is executed:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: would it not blow up if a variable doesn't exist?

Comment: @4c74356b41, Can you give a concrete example? In the answer, I just define it statically for testing. In fact, we are more dynamically getting the value of the variable. If this value does not exist, we will run a specific task.

Comment: if the variable doesnt exist, not the value, also its a question, not a statement

Comment: My case is the case of the "variable doesn't exist", however, it works! Thank you!